# Heroku からダウンロードしたデータベースのファイルを開くには

Tags: heroku

Herokuについて質問します。基本的なことにて、失礼します。

Heroku上のデータベースからダウンロードしたデータのファイルを開くことができません。

Macの「メモ」や「テキストエディット」それに「Excel」や「Word」でも同様です。

質問です。
Herokuからダウンロードしたデータを開くには、pgAdminなどPostgreSQLの管理ツールを利用するしか方法はないのでしょうか？（本音を言ってしまえば、そのためだけにPostgreSQLをマスターするのは、ちっとシンドイ感じが..）

参考までに、Herokuからダウンロードする際のコマンドは以下になります。

```
heroku pg:backups download -a $アプリ名$
```

以上、よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 0):

Heroku は実際に使っているわけではないので、今回の回答にあたって少し調べた程度です。

標準のバックアップだと dump 形式というバイナリデータになっているため、PostgresSQL のデータが扱えるクライアント等が必要になりますが、`pg_dump` コマンドを使ってプレーンテキスト形式でバックアップすれば、(テキスト形式が扱える) 任意のアプリでも中身の確認だけであればできそうです。

[How can I get a plain text postgres database dump on heroku?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22887524) での [Alex さんの回答](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22896985)

- `heroku config:get DATABASE_URL` を実行して結果を取得します。
- 取得した結果の中から PostgresSQL の情報を探します。
  例: `HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_RED_URL: postgres://user3123:passkja83kd8@ec2-117-21-174-214.compute-1.amazonaws.com:6212/db982398`
  これは次の様なフォーマットです: `postgres://<username>:<password>@<host_name>:<port>/<dbname>`
- 次のコマンドを実行します。

  ```
  pg_dump --host=<host_name> --port=<port> --username=<username> --password --dbname=<dbname> > output.sql
  ```

Comment: いろいろやっていますが、どうしても「zsh: parse error near `>'」となってしまいます。

ちなみに、以下をそのままコピペしても、同様の表示となります。

pg_dump --host=<host_name> --port=<port> --username=<username> --password --dbname=<dbname> > output.sql

なにか、もし、お気づきの点がありましたら、ぜひ。

Comment: `< ... >` の部分はそのまま入力するのではなく、 `heroku config:get DATABASE_URL` の結果を元にそれぞれ適切な値に置き換える必要があります。

Comment: コメント、ありがとうございます。説明が舌足らずで申し訳ありません。<・・・＞には、heroku config:get DATABASE_URLにより得たそれぞれの値を、postgres://<username>:<password>@<host_name>:<port>/<dbname>に入れてやっています。その結果、「zsh: parse error near `>'」という表示が出てしまうのです。

Comment: 値を置き換える際に `< >` 記号は不要ですが、この点は間違いないですか？(リダイレクトの `>` 以外でこの記号は使いません)。回答に含めたリンク先にも一度目を通してみることをお勧めします。

Comment: コメント、ありがとうございます。ご指摘のとおり、<>を含めておりました。

<>抜きでやったところ、パスワードを求められたので、HerokuのIDに対するPasswordを入力したところ、エラー表示となります。

HrokuのPasswordは確実に入れています。（記憶にないのですが...）もしかしたら、データベースのパスワードというのが存在していたりするのでしょうか。もう少しだけ、お付き合い頂けると幸いです。

Comment: <<追記>>パスワードを入力した後、このように表示されます。ご参照くださいませ。

https://github.com/okahijiki/snowpeaks/issues/4

Comment: 試行錯誤したところ、現状は、貼っていただいたコマンドのうち、以下の通り、パスワードを省く仕様になっているようです。

```
pg_dump --host=<host_name> --port=<port> --username=<username> --dbname=<dbname> > output.sql
```

そうすると、次にパスワードが求められるので（上記の省いた）パスワードを記述します...

がしかし、今度は、何も表示されず（エラーコードさえ表示されず）終わってしまいます。
ダウンロードするデータが重すぎるか、あるいは管理者権限云々に原因があるのでは、と、現在のところ推測しています。